# EF Core Fluent API, set IsRequired on all entities to generate a non-null db column

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I'm working on a Razor pages web app which works directly with a db context...yes this is not ideal but is what I'm stuck with for the time being.

In the data model, each object inherits from a base entity class containing audit data, e.g.:

```
public class BaseEntity
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
    ...etc.

public class Table1 : BaseEntity
{
    public string TestItemName { get; set; }
}
```

In the database, I want CreatedBy to be required (not null), but I don't want to use the [Required] attribute since this will trigger the UI to validate the CreatedBy column.  I don't want to expose this column in the UI and instead have service code which updates all of the audit properties based on Add/Insert.

What I'm looking for is a way via Fluent API which will give me the column type in the db that I need, e.g. NVARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL.

I can accomplish this in the OnModelCreating method in the dbcontext:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Table1>()
        .Property(o => o.CreatedBy)
        .IsRequired();
```

However this would require me to create a similar entry for every table in the model.

Is there code I can use in OnModelCreating which could accomplish this for all entities?  Something like this (this is just pseudo-code, but looking to give an idea):

```
var entityTypes = modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes().Select(o => o.GetType()).ToList();
entityTypes.ForEach(e =>
{
    e.Property("CreatedBy").IsRequired();
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implement your entity configurations in discrete classes that implement `IEntityTypeConfiguration`.  Your implementations should inherit from a base implementation that configures `BaseEntity` and the `Configure` method should be virtual with overriding implementations calling the base class' method:

```
public abstract class BaseEntityConfiguration<TEntity>
    : IEntityTypeConfiguration<TEntity>
        where TEntity : BaseEntity
{
    public virtual void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<TEntity> builder)
    {
        builder.Property(be => be.CreatedBy)
            .IsRequired();

        // etc
    }
}

public class SomeEntityConfiguration : BaseEntityConfiguration<SomeEntity>
{
    public override void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<SomeEntity> builder)
    {
        // call base class method to configure BaseEntity properties
        base.Configure(builder);

        // configure remaining SomeEntity-specific properties/etc
        builder.TestItemName.IsRequired();
    }
}
```

You'll need to inform the model builder to use your configuration classes.  For example, if your config classes are in the same assembly as your `DbContext`:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.ApplyConfigurationsFromAssembly(
        typeof(YourDbContext).Assembly);
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Moho, great solution, tested and works well.  I had hoped to apply something quicker and more generic via some sort of ForEach to keep things simple and not have to create an entry for each entity in the model, but I can also see the value of having custom configuration class too (and have already used it for something else).  Appreciate your time!